# Spring Boot application OracleDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, intellij-idea

When launching a Spring Boot application in IntelliJ using the Spring Boot Application run configuration, running with Java 1.8, I am receiving the following message (only one listed for brevity's sake - but the same exception for each of the attempted URLs):

```
 Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@redacted.redacted.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1234/abcd"
```

I have seen the recommendations on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56054353/driver-oracle-jdbc-oracledriver-claims-to-not-accept-jdbcurl) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51476040/oracledriver-not-accept-jdbcurl-jdbcoraclethinlocalhost1521-orcl/51476212#51476212) but I have been unsuccessful in determining the root of the problem.

My configurations are as follows - I am using EnvFile locally to provide for values that are normally handled by Vault in our deployed environments.

`application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url="${DATASOURCE_URL}"
spring.datasource.driver-class-name="${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME}"
```

`environment value`

```
DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:oracle:thin:@redacted.redacted.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/abcd

# I have tried the following
# jdbc:oracle:thin:@redacted.redacted.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/abcd
# jdbc:oracle:thin:@redacted.redacted.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:abcd
# jdbc:oracle:thin://@redacted.redacted.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521:abcd
# jdbc:oracle:thin://@redacted.redacted.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/abcd

SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

`pom.xml`

```
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>
...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
      <version>19.9.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The URL format appears to be correct as compared to the previous answer on this issue. What else might be causing the problem here?

Comment: Did you also try putting a semicolon between the host and the database in stead of a slash like the other Q&A has? So `:abcd`  in stead of `/abcd`? That's also what the answerer changed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51476212/1915448).

Comment: (I meant a colon in stead of a semicolon in my previous comment, woops, can't edit it now).

Comment: Unfortunately the other question did not answer my issue, as noted where I linked to that post in my question.

Comment: Please note that I refered to a different question than the one you linked. The answer you linked only tells you to include a colon after the "thin". Also, in your properties file you mentioned you tried `jdbc:oracle:thin:` and `jdbc:oracle:thin://`. But in both cases you use `/abcd` and not `:abcd`. Even the error message only includes `/abcd` and not `:abcd`. I suggest you edit your question and list all attempts you made.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - I looked at this so much that the posts started to look the same! I've updated the question to show the permutations I have attempted.

Comment: I was able to get around this error by using the Docker run configuration instead of the Spring Boot run configuration. While this does not explain why the problem persists in the Spring Boot run configuration, I am hoping this comment will at least help somebody in the future if they run into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause of this error was an incorrect/missing password  value for the `Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` within the `ENTRYPOINT` of the Dockerfile. Once I corrected this and rebuilt the image, subsequent runs did not experience this behavior.